# COPY ... FROM STDIN command failing on null values exported as "\N"

Tags: postgresql, psql

I initiated a table dump and wherever the NULL value comes, the dump file has `\N` for that.

During the restore I'm getting this error.

> invalid command \N

The database encoding is `UTF8`.

I took the dump and tried to restore on the same server but the different database. There are some workaround for this. But still I'm trying to fix it without do any further changes on the database encoding.

### Table Stucture:

```
CREATE TABLE person.person (
    businessentityid integer NOT NULL,
    persontype character(2) NOT NULL,
    namestyle public."NameStyle" DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    title character varying(8),
    firstname public."Name" NOT NULL,
    middlename public."Name",
    lastname public."Name" NOT NULL,
    suffix character varying(10),
    emailpromotion integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    additionalcontactinfo xml,
    demographics xml,
    rowguid uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v1() NOT NULL,
    modifieddate timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "CK_Person_EmailPromotion" CHECK (((emailpromotion >= 0) AND (emailpromotion <= 2))),
    CONSTRAINT "CK_Person_PersonType" CHECK (((persontype IS NULL) OR (upper((persontype)::text) = ANY (ARRAY['SC'::text, 'VC'::text, 'IN'::text, 'EM'::text, 'SP'::text, 'GC'::text]))))
);
```

### Error line

```
COPY person.person (businessentityid, persontype, namestyle, title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, emailpromotion, additionalcontactinfo, demographics, rowguid, modifieddate) FROM stdin;
1       EM      f       \N      Ken     J       Sánchez \N      0       \N      <IndividualSurvey xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/IndividualSurvey"><TotalPurchaseYTD>0</TotalPurchaseYTD></IndividualSurvey>     92c4279f-1207-48a3-8448-4636514eb7e2    2009-01-07 00:00:00
```

Comment: Do you have a location that you can share?  Where in the dump file is it failing? Which table?  Which row?  What are the contents?

Comment: Question updated with the error line

Comment: and what is the table structure?

Comment: @richyen included in the question.

Comment: Its adventure works database dump.

Comment: There probably is an error **before** that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most plausible root cause is that the `person.person` table was not created because some of these reasons:

- it refers to `public.uuid_generate_v1()` which requires the `uuid-ossp` extension that may not be installed, especially if it's a table dump, not a database dump (so it wouldn't have the CREATE EXTENSION statement)
- it refers to custom types `public."NameStyle"`  and `public."Name"` that also may not exist.

By default, psql doesn't stop at the first error, so in this case it would continue to the `COPY` command, which would fail and leave the input stream at the next line.
This line and others below it contain inline data, but psql doesn't know that and interprets them as commands, which typically leads to **invalid command \N** errors.

**Solution**: use `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f script.sql` and solve the errors as they appear in chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

this was in another post to use this option on loading the file.

```
psql -P 'null=\N'
```

If you want to stop in any errors add `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1`

This seams to work for me, it stops if I get an error. Only pain was I had to drop the tables a

```
psql --host=<> --dbname=<> --username=<>  -P 'null=\N' -f <script file>
```